# Why is distributing the definitions of a list of arbitrary precision numbers so slow?

Tags: parallelization, arbitrary-precision

For a parallel application I need to make a large list of numbers available to the parallel kernels, which I do using DistributeDefinitions. I have noticed that this is much slower when the numbers are arbitrary precision numbers compared to normal floats.

Suppose I have 2 tables:

```
tab1=Table[RandomReal[],{10^6}]
tab2=SetPrecision[tab1,10]
```

Then Distributing the definitions (over 4 subkernels) of each

```
DistributeDefinitions[tab1]; // AbsoluteTiming
DistributeDefinitions[tab2]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

completes almost instantly (0.007 seconds) for tab1 and takes over 4 seconds.

Now, of course, arbitrary precision numbers take more memory. (The ByteCount of tab2 is ten times as large as that of tab1). But even accounting for that by considering a smaller table

```
tab3=tab2[[1;;-1;;10]];
```

The time to distribute this ten times smaller table which has the same ByteCount as tab1 is still 0.4 seconds.

Can somebody explain to me why this is case? (And hopefully give some tips on avoiding this?)

PS. Related to this, why is the time taken by DistributeDefinitions approximately linear in the number of kernels?

Comment: I suspect that the real question is about the performance of MathLink.  It is entirely possible that I remember wrong (!!), but I think that arbitrary precision numbers are transferred as strings while machine precision numbers as normal binary floating point numbers.  Also, the C MathLink API has functions for putting/getting a *whole array* of machine numbers, but not arbitrary precision numbers.

Comment: In the end it is not the `ByteCount` that matters.  `ByteCount` tells how how much space something would take up *in kernel memory* without any subexpression sharing (see `Share`).  I'm pretty sure that expressions don't use the same representation as in kernel memory when they are being transferred through a MathLink link.  There are also some weird effect relating to the size of the encoding, see e.g. how transfer through a JSON string was faster than standard MathLink array transfer [here](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/575100).

Comment: The fact that the distributed array is packed or not packed seems to have an impact (`tab1` is packed but not `tab2`). Compare for instance ``tab1u = Developer`FromPackedArray[tab1];

RepeatedTiming[DistributeDefinitions[tab1u];]`` and 

`RepeatedTiming[DistributeDefinitions[tab3];]`.

Comment: @xavier Packed or not packed would correspond to one MathLink call to send the array, or one call for each element.

Comment: "why is the time taken by DistributeDefinitions approximately linear in the number of kernels?"  I assume it's because the main kernel has to send separately to each kernel.  At least the MathLink put operations must be performed as many times as you have subkernels.  Since they're all done by the main kernel, they are likely done sequentially.  This is an educated guess, as I don't fully understand MathLink, neither is it fully documented.

Comment: To add (I hope) to what @Szabolcs and others have said, with bignums there is a conversion to/from formats whereas with a packed array of machine doubles the transfer over MathLink requires no format conversions. I would expect these conversions to be costly in terms of speed.

Comment: Thanks All for the comments. The conjectured that this is due to limitations of the Mathlink protocol requiring some conversion in the transfer, seems reasonable (and consistent with observations.)